# Javascript: shasum of SHELL and crypto of JS library are giving different results

Tags: javascript, hash, browserify, sha256, cryptojs

Here's what Unix gives me and it is correct:

```
shasum -a 256 test.jpg
df94ac3fd72415827f345b5fa22761f57d87e99c25d5345d2e8e9f6c91ef34a3  test.jpg
```

In Javascript, I am not able to get this using `crypto-browserify`. Please see my results:

```
img.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(e.path[0]).digest('hex'));
    console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(e.path).digest('hex'));
    console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(e.path[0].src).digest('hex'));
    console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(e).digest('hex'));
}
```

The results are:

```
da5698be17b9b46962335799779fbeca8ce5d491c0e26243bafef9ea1837a9d8
6e340b9cffb37a989ca54ee6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d
7ce85f64d69c7a8865413deaff3d65ca0272dfbe74ad9bc07s5e28679243cb69
da5698be17b9b46962335799779fbeca8ce5d491csd26243bafef9ea1837a9d8
```

Not able to get `df94ac3fd72415827f345b5fa22761f57d87e99c25d5345d2e8e9f6c91ef34a3` like in `shasum` command line. Could you please tell what should I do get the `sha`?

Comment: Your just doing a digest of the filename, not the file contents.. So they will be different.

Comment: How can I do it for the file content? @Keith

Comment: If you look here you can get the file contents -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally implemented:

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "../test.jpg", true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
        var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
        if (arrayBuffer) {
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(byteArray).digest('hex'));
        }
    };
    oReq.send(null);
```

Thanks,
Keith.